Pull data from one Sheet to another Sheet based on the Header names, headers in different order
I can't believe I can't figure this out but I keep getting errors.
Example sheets are found at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q4qRgXSq6xXhddArPCoBIuOOupRvokUd0andADCNN0Q/edit?usp=sharing
'Sheet10' lets people choose the Header order in Sheet 11.
'Sheet11' uses the headers from 'Sheet10'. I need a formula for A2 that will populate the column with data from 'Sheet12' where the header has the same name. Note, the headers in 'Sheet12' are in a different order than in 'Sheet11'.
'Sheet12' is the existing data.
The ideal formula for 'Sheet11'!A2 would populate each column with the column of data in Sheet12 based on the column names.

From the [tag:google-sheets] tag wiki: Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead.

You can use:
=MAP(A1:E1,LAMBDA(h,FILTER(Sheet12!A2:E,Sheet12!A1:E1=h)))


Thank you - I adjusted it to use an arbitrary number of columns with the following: =iferror(MAP(A1:Z1, LAMBDA(h, FILTER(Sheet12!A2:Z, Sheet12!A1:Z1=h))))

Here's one formula you could try entering in Sheet11's A2 cell and dragging across the row:
=FILTER(Sheet12!$A$2:$E$6, Sheet12!$A$1:$E$1=A1)

FILTER selects the column in sheet Sheet12 that matches the header.

Here is one formula to be entered in A2 that will output the whole array:
=LET(indexes, ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(A1:E1, Sheet12!A1:E1, 0)), CHOOSECOLS(Sheet12!A2:E6, indexes))

The ARRAYFORMULA version of MATCH returns the indexes of the columns in sheet Sheet12, in the order they appear in sheet Sheet11. So, in this case, it will output: 2, 3, 5, 1, 4.
Then, CHOOSECOLS fetches the columns of the data range in that order.
References

FILTER
LET
MATCH
CHOOSECOLS


Works great, thank you! I marked the other as the solution because it was easier for me to adjust to work for an arbitrary number of columns. But this works very well and is probably better on performance than the other solution.
